# How can we draw pie chart with different radius in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, charts, pie-chart

In flutter, I am trying to implement **a pie chart with different radius** in each slice as shown in figure below? I searched and tried different plugins in [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/), but didn't find any plugin with my requirements. How can I do this in *flutter*?
Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lib fl_chart can help you.

https://pub.dev/packages/fl_chart

The use is very simple, you can pass the radius value in PieChartSectionData, which can be the same of the value or you can configure for other purpose:

```
PieChart(
PieChartData(centerSpaceRadius: 30, sections: [
PieChartSectionData(
    color: const Color(0xff0293ee),
    value: 40,
    title: '40%',
    radius: 40,
    titleStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 12,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        color: const Color(0xffffffff)),
),
PieChartSectionData(
    color: const Color(0xfff8b250),
    value: 30,
    title: '30%',
    radius: 30,
    titleStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 14,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        color: const Color(0xffffffff)),
)
]))
```

Pie Chart with different radius values result:

[image: Pie Chart with different radius values]

Comment: Is it possible to make the slices "grow" to the opposite direction, that is, to the center of the donut?